# How to build a complex and dynamic textbox-control? (for name:value pair)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am working on a asp.net site.
For this I need a very complex site: I need to have a site in which a user can enter as much Name:Value-pairs as he wants, save them to a database from backend on click, delete this pairs while edeting and add new ones.

Here is a screenshot from a other page where i found such thing:
http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3377/rm8zzcqe_jpg.htm

As you see you have 2 textboxes, can delete every pair on the right, add textboxes as much as you want and after this, save it, done.

I have very good asp.net knowlegde but less JS knowlegde and I think 99% of this code will be JS, so im a little helpless here.

How to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple resources and tips that will hopefully point you in the right direction.

**Implementing drag/drop:**  check out jQueryUI library for examples http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

**Adding/removing text boxes:**  Add a piece of JS code that will create html input elements with appropriate IDs that you can track.

**Storing data on the client side:** you can keep the data in a two dimensional array that looks like

```
//Lets assume that there are not more than 100 elements

var x = new Array(100);
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     x[i] = new Array(2);
}

x[0][0] = "textboxID";
x[0][1] = "value1:value2";

x[1][0] = "textboxID2";
x[1][1] = "value3:value4";
```

**Sending data to the server:**  Simplest way is to convert those values into JSON string that you can put in a hidden field and then find on the server.

Comment: Thank you, this is very complex, can you add a few more lines code please?